# PL SQL IF-THEN-ELSE block

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have this piece of code that is embedded in my sql. For some reason, I see that every time my last ELSE block is getting executed. Here is my code:

```
 IF REGEXP_LIKE (UPPER(V_TEMP_DEPT_1),
        'DEP|DPT$|ABT|DIP.|DIPART|AFDEL|AVDEL|AVD.|DIV|PGRD|PGP|PPG|FAC|AMU|LAB|WING|
          UNIT|SERV|AFT|CENT|CLIN|KLIN|ETHICS COM|EC|IRB') THEN
              V_DEPT_N    := V_TEMP_DEPT_1;
              V_ADDR_LINE1:= NULL;
      ELSE

      IF REGEXP_LIKE (UPPER(V_TEMP_DEPT_2),
      'DEP|DPT$|ABT|DIP.|DIPART|AFDEL|AVDEL|AVD.|DIV|PGRD|PGP|PPG|FAC|AMU|LAB|WING|
        UNIT|SERV|AFT|CENT|CLIN|KLIN|ETHICS COM|EC|IRB') THEN
            V_DEPT_N    := V_TEMP_DEPT_2;
            V_ADDR_LINE2:= NULL;
                    ELSE

      IF REGEXP_LIKE (UPPER(V_TEMP_DEPT_3),
          'DEP|DPT$|ABT|DIP.|DIPART|AFDEL|AVDEL|AVD.|DIV|PGRD|PGP|PPG|FAC|AMU|LAB|WING|
            UNIT|SERV|AFT|CENT|CLIN|KLIN|ETHICS COM|EC|IRB') THEN
              V_DEPT_N    := V_TEMP_DEPT_3;
              V_ADDR_LINE3:= NULL;
      ELSE

      IF REGEXP_LIKE (UPPER(V_TEMP_DEPT_4),
          'DEP|DPT$|ABT|DIP.|DIPART|AFDEL|AVDEL|AVD.|DIV|PGRD|PGP|PPG|FAC|AMU|LAB|WING|
            UNIT|SERV|AFT|CENT|CLIN|KLIN|ETHICS COM|EC|IRB') THEN
              V_DEPT_N    := V_TEMP_DEPT_4;
              V_ADDR_LINE4:= NULL;
      ELSE
              -- The below line always gets executed.
              V_DEPT_N:= NULL;

      END IF;
        END IF;
          END IF;
            END IF;
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is in `V_TEMP_DEPT_<<1-4>>`?  Is there a value in at least one of these variables that you believe should match the regular expression?  Have you tested the regular expression against this data separately to verify that the regular expression matches what you think it should match?

Comment: Yeah I did test it and its working fine. Btw this whole code is inside a loop. Do you want me to put the entire code here? Its like 130 lines...

Comment: The most helpful thing you can post is the simplest test case that you can create that demonstrates the problem that we can run on our local systems.  Do you need the loop to demonstrate the problem?  If so, include it.  If not, eliminate it when you put together the test case.  Do you need all 4 `IF` statements to demonstrate the problem?  If so, include all 4.  If not, only post 1 or 2 or whatever the smallest number of `IF` statements that demonstrate the problem.

Comment: ahh nevermind i solved it. i am posting the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF REGEXP_LIKE (UPPER(V_TEMP_DEPT_1),
    'DEP|DPT$|ABT|DIP.|DIPART|AFDEL|AVDEL|AVD.|DIV|PGRD|PGP|PPG|FAC|AMU|LAB|WING|
      UNIT|SERV|AFT|CENT|CLIN|KLIN|ETHICS COM|EC|IRB') THEN
          V_DEPT_N    := V_TEMP_DEPT_1;
          V_ADDR_LINE1:= NULL;

  ELSIF REGEXP_LIKE (UPPER(V_TEMP_DEPT_2),
  'DEP|DPT$|ABT|DIP.|DIPART|AFDEL|AVDEL|AVD.|DIV|PGRD|PGP|PPG|FAC|AMU|LAB|WING|
    UNIT|SERV|AFT|CENT|CLIN|KLIN|ETHICS COM|EC|IRB') THEN
        V_DEPT_N    := V_TEMP_DEPT_2;
        V_ADDR_LINE2:= NULL;

  ELSIF REGEXP_LIKE (UPPER(V_TEMP_DEPT_3),
      'DEP|DPT$|ABT|DIP.|DIPART|AFDEL|AVDEL|AVD.|DIV|PGRD|PGP|PPG|FAC|AMU|LAB|WING|
        UNIT|SERV|AFT|CENT|CLIN|KLIN|ETHICS COM|EC|IRB') THEN
          V_DEPT_N    := V_TEMP_DEPT_3;
          V_ADDR_LINE3:= NULL;

  ELSIF REGEXP_LIKE (UPPER(V_TEMP_DEPT_4),
      'DEP|DPT$|ABT|DIP.|DIPART|AFDEL|AVDEL|AVD.|DIV|PGRD|PGP|PPG|FAC|AMU|LAB|WING|
        UNIT|SERV|AFT|CENT|CLIN|KLIN|ETHICS COM|EC|IRB') THEN
          V_DEPT_N    := V_TEMP_DEPT_4;
          V_ADDR_LINE4:= NULL;
  ELSE
          -- Now this works!!
          V_DEPT_N:= NULL;

  END IF;
```